# What does "the princess and the queen" refer to here?

Tags: the-sandman, reference

In volume 36 of the fairly entertaining Sandman written by Neil Gaiman, George calls Barbara and Wanda "the princess and the queen". Wanda appears to not take kindly to it.

> George: Heeheeeheeeheee.
>
> Wanda: What's so funny, George?
>
> George: You're the princess and the queen. Heeheehee. Get it? Uh the princess and the uh queen. Heehee.
>
> Wanda: You know, death really hasn't improved you one little bit, George.

So, what is the joke about?

I tried googling this, but whatever meaning this idiom had before GRRM's eponymous novella, it's lost to history now.

[image: Two panels, one with a bloody head with nails stuck into it with its tongue out, and the other showing a woman with red hair. The dialogue is transcribed above, with the head being George and the woman Wanda.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Queen" is sometimes used as a shortened version of "drag queen," i.e. man who performs dressed as a woman (usually- there's a lot of nuance there that is beyond the scope of this question). As Wanda is a transgender woman, she may have had this kind of language leveraged against her before in a disparaging way.

Comment: You might want to compare this to "princess" Barbie